# What does "Recursive type bound" in Generics mean?

Tags: java, generics, effective-java

I am reading the chapter on Generics from Effective Java[Item 27].

There is this paragraph in the book:

> *It is permissible, though relatively rare, for a type parameter to be bounded by some expression involving that type parameter itself. This is what’s known as a recursive type bound.*

and this:

```
// Using a recursive type bound to express mutual comparability
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(List<T> list) {...}
```

What is  recursive type bound  and how does the above piece of code help achieve mutual comparability?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> What is recursive type bound

This: `<T extends Comparable<T>>`

Note that the type parameter `T` is also part of the signature of the super interface `Comparable<T>`.

> and how does the above piece of code help achieve mutual comparability?

It ensures that you can only compare objects of type `T`. Without the type bound, `Comparable` compares any two `Object`s. With the type bound, the compiler can ensure that only two objects of type `T` are compared.

Answer (score 43):

To understand the concept of recursive type bounds, let's solve a simple problem. This concept is easier to understand by solving a real problem. I'll provide the definition of the recursive type bound at the end, because it makes more sense after understanding the concept.

---

### Problem

Assume that we have to sort the fruits by their sizes. And we are told that we can only compare fruits of the same types. For example, we can't compare apples with oranges (pun intended).

So, we create a simple type hierarchy like following,

**Fruit.java**

```
interface Fruit {
    Integer getSize();
}
```

**Apple.java**

```
class Apple implements Fruit, Comparable<Apple> {
    private final Integer size;

    public Apple(Integer size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override public Integer getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override public int compareTo(Apple other) {
        return size.compareTo(other.size);
    }
}
```

**Orange.java**

```
class Orange implements Fruit, Comparable<Orange> {
    private final Integer size;

    public Orange(Integer size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    @Override public Integer getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override public int compareTo(Orange other) {
        return size.compareTo(other.size);
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Apple apple1 = new Apple(3);
        Apple apple2 = new Apple(4);
        apple1.compareTo(apple2);

        Orange orange1 = new Orange(3);
        Orange orange2 = new Orange(4);
        orange1.compareTo(orange2);

        apple1.compareTo(orange1);  // Error: different types
    }
}
```

**Solution**

In this code, we are able to achieve our objective of being able to compare the same types, that is, apples with apples and oranges with oranges. When we compare an apple with an orange we get an error which is what we want.

**Problem**

The problem here is that the code for implementing the `compareTo()` method is duplicated for `Apple` and `Orange` class. And will be duplicated more in all the classes that we extend from the `Fruit`, for creating new fruits in the future. The amount of repeated code in our example is less but in real world the repeated code can be of hundreds of lines in each class.

---

### Moving Repeated Code to Common Class

**Fruit.java**

```
class Fruit implements Comparable<Fruit> {
    private final Integer size;

    public Fruit(Integer size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public Integer getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override public int compareTo(Fruit other) {
        return size.compareTo(other.getSize());
    }
}
```

**Apple.java**

```
class Apple extends Fruit {
    public Apple(Integer size) {
        super(size);
    }
}
```

**Orange.java**

```
class Orange extends Fruit {
    public Orange(Integer size) {
        super(size);
    }
}
```

**Solution**

In this step, we get rid of the repeated code of `compareTo()` method by moving it to a superclass. Our extended classes `Apple` and `Orange` are no longer polluted with common code.

**Problem**

Here the problem is that we are now able to compare different types, comparing apples to oranges no longer gives us an error:

```
apple1.compareTo(orange1);    // No error
```

---

### Introducing a Type Parameter

**Fruit.java**

```
class Fruit<T> implements Comparable<T> {
    private final Integer size;

    public Fruit(Integer size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public Integer getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override public int compareTo(T other) {
        return size.compareTo(other.getSize());     // Error: getSize() not available.
    }
}
```

**Apple.java**

```
class Apple extends Fruit<Apple> {
    public Apple(Integer size) {
        super(size);
    }
}
```

**Orange.java**

```
class Orange extends Fruit<Orange> {
    public Orange(Integer size) {
        super(size);
    }
}
```

**Solution**

To restrict comparison of different types, we introduce a type parameter `T`. So that the comparable `Fruit<Apple>` cannot be compared to comparable `Fruit<Orange>`. Note our `Apple` and `Orange` classes; they now inherit from the types `Fruit<Apple>` and `Fruit<Orange>` respectively. Now if we try to compare different types, the IDE shows an error, our desired behaviour:

```
apple1.compareTo(orange1);  // Error: different types
```

**Problem**

But in this step, our `Fruit` class doesn't compile. The `getSize()` method of `T` is unknown to the compiler. This is because the type parameter `T` of our
`Fruit` class doesn't have any bound. So, the `T` could be any class, it is not possible that every class would have a `getSize()` method. So the compiler is right in not recognizing the `getSize()` method of `T`.

---

### Introducing a Recursive Type Bound

**Fruit.java**

```
class Fruit<T extends Fruit<T>> implements Comparable<T> {
    private final Integer size;

    public Fruit(Integer size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public Integer getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override public int compareTo(T other) {
        return size.compareTo(other.getSize());     // Now getSize() is available.
    }
}
```

**Apple.java**

```
class Apple extends Fruit<Apple> {
    public Apple(Integer size) {
        super(size);
    }
}
```

**Orange.java**

```
class Orange extends Fruit<Orange> {
    public Orange(Integer size) {
        super(size);
    }
}
```

**Final Solution**

So, we tell the compiler that our `T` is a subtype of `Fruit`. In other words, we specify the upper bound `T extends Fruit<T>`. This makes sure that only subtypes of `Fruit` are allowed as type arguments. Now the compiler knows that the `getSize()` method can be found in the subtype of `Fruit` class (`Apple`, `Orange` etc.) because the `Comparable<T>` also receives our type(`Fruit<T>`) that contains the `getSize()` method.

This allows us to get rid of the repeated code of `compareTo()` method and also allows us to compare the fruits of the same types, apples with apples and oranges with oranges.

Now the `compareTo()` method can be used inside the `max()` function given in the question.

---

### Definition of a Recursive Type Bound

In generics, when a reference type has a type parameter that is bounded by the reference type itself, then that type parameter is said to have a recursive type bound.

In our example, the generic type `Fruit<T extends Fruit<T>>`, `Fruit` is our reference type, its type parameter `T` is bounded by the `Fruit` itself, so, the type parameter `T` has a recursive type bound `Fruit<T>`.

A recursive type is one that includes a function that uses that type itself as a type for some argument or its return value. In our example, `compareTo(T other)` is the function of the recursive type that takes the same recursive type as an argument.

---

### Caveat

There is a caveat in this pattern. The compiler doesn’t prevent us from creating a class with a type argument of another subtype:

```
class Orange extends Fruit<Orange> {...}
class Apple extends Fruit<Orange> {...}    // No error
```

Note in the `Apple` class above, by mistake we passed `Orange` instead of the `Apple` itself as a type argument. This results in the `compareTo(T other)` method to take `Orange` instead of `Apple`. Now we no longer get error while comparing different types and suddenly not able to compare apples with apples:

```
apple1.compareTo(apple2);     // Error
apple1.compareTo(orange1);    // No error
```

So, the developer needs to be careful while extending the classes.

---

That's it! Hope that helps.

Comment: This is a great answer! Thank you for taking the time to break it down this way.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I have a question. If the entire motive of the recursive type is to establish an upper bound for ```T``` , then in "Introducing a Type Parameter" section, why can't we just write ```public class Fruit <T> implements Comparable<T extends Fruit>```? When I try it, my IDE says "Unexpected Bound". Shouldn't that be enough to tell the compiler that ```T``` is meant to be a subclass of Fruit?

Comment: @rgbk21, we cannot change the type of an already existing class or interface like `Comparable`, because it's declared as `Comparable<T>` and not `Comparable<T extends SomeClass>` in the Java library. It is a contract that we have to fullfill. Whatever bound you specify on `Fruit` is automatically passed on to `Comparable<T>`. For example, if you write `Fruit<T extends Fruit<T>>` then the `Comparable` will automatically receive `Fruit<T>` under the hood. Also note that the objective of the *recursive* type bound is to establish the bound of that type itself. Hope that clears your doubts.

Comment: Bravo, Bravo, Bravo !!!

Answer (score 10):

There is an entry in the Java Generics FAQ written by Angelika Langer which explains the details of such declaration: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ106