# What does V <: Vector[V] mean in scala?

Tags: scala

Hi I come across this piece of code, but could not understand this. The confusing place is "V <: Vector[V]", this means V is a subtype of Vector[V] ? very confusing here.

```
trait Vector[V <: Vector[V]] { this: V =>
  def +(other: V): V
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called [F-bounded type polymorphism](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/papers/FBound89/CookFBound89.pdf) and

> is usually attempted when someone is trying to solve a common problem
>   of abstraction in object-oriented languages: how to define a
>   polymorphic function that, though defined in terms of a supertype,
>   will when passed a value of some subtype will always return a value of
>   the same subtype as its argument.

(from a recent blog post "[F-Bounded Type Polymorphism Considered Tricky](http://logji.blogspot.com/2012/11/f-bounded-type-polymorphism-give-up-now.html)" by [Kris Nuttycombe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390636/kris-nuttycombe))

Also see this SO question: [What does "Recursive type bound" in Generics mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385949/what-does-recursive-type-bound-in-generics-mean)