# Is there any good way to define Monoid interface?

Tags: go, math, interface

I'd like to define structure like "Monoid". (This is a word which appears in [Group-Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid).)

Here's one example of Monoid-Structure.

Example(1):

```
type monoid_sum struct{
    val int
}

func op(x,y monoid_sum) monoid_sum {
    return monoid_sum{x.val + y.val}
}

func ide() monoid_sum{
    return monoid_sum{0}
}
```

---

Example(2):

```
import "math"

func max(a,b int) int{
    if a > b{
            return a
    }else{
            return b
    }
}

type monoid_max struct {
    val int
}

func op(x,y monoid_max) monoid_max {
    return monoid_max{max(x.val,y.val)}
}

func ide() monoid_max {
    return monoid_max{math.MinInt}
}
```

Is there any good way to define a monoid interface? I want to make an interface like this:

```
type monoid interface{
    op func(monoid) monoid // mapping_function(monoid,monoid) -> monoid（binary operations in monoid)
    ide() monoid          // identity_function() -> monoid (return Identity element)

}
```

though the codes does not work(just Pseudo code)

Comment: I want to make interface like:


type monoid interface{
    op func(monoid) monoid // mapping_function(monoid,monoid) -> monoid（binary operations in monoid)
    ide () monoid          // identity_function() -> monoid (return Identity element)

}

though the codes does not work(this is just Pseudo code)

Comment: in this case define methods (op,ide) with receivers, and change `return` type and `arg` type to `monoid`.

Comment: `type monoid interface { Op(monoid) monoid; ide() monoid }`

Comment: Not sure I would encourage trying to implement such algebraic structures in Go, but this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64468241/recursive-type-constraint-using-a-defined-type-rather-than-a-type-literal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to follow the interface definitions as they are defined for struct to implement the interface. When interface defines return type as `monoid` for your `op` method, you'll have to return monoid in when implementing that interface. See if following helps:

```golang
type monoid interface{
    get() int
    op(monoid, monoid) monoid   // mapping_function(monoid,monoid) -> monoid（binary operations in monoid)
    ide() monoid                // identity_function() -> monoid (return Identity element)
}

func max(a,b int) int{
    if a > b{
        return a
    }else{
        return b
    }
}

type monoid2 struct{
    val int
}

func (m monoid2) get() int {
    return m.val
}

func (monoid2) op(x,y monoid) monoid{
    return monoid2{max(x.get(),y.get())}
}

func (monoid2) ide() monoid{
    return monoid2{-math.MaxInt8}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define the `Monoid` interface as the following generic interface:

```
type Monoid[T any] interface {
    Identity() T
    Combine(T) T
}
```

`Combine()` corresponds to the monoid's (associative) binary operation, and `Identity()` returns the monoid's identity element. You called them `op()` and `ide()`, respectively.

`CombineMonoids` is a generic convenience function for combining an arbitrary number of monoids into a single monoid:

```
func CombineMonoids[M Monoid[M]](ms ...M) M {
    var res M
    res = res.Identity()
    for _, m := range ms {
        res = res.Combine(m)
    }
    return res
}
```

The constraint `Monoid[M]` on the type parameter `M` – i.e., `M Monoid[M]` – means that it works with any type `M` that has the methods `Identity() M` and `Combine(M) M`, i.e., it satisfies `Monoid[M]`.

### Examples

For example, here are the types `SumMonoid` and `MaxMonoid` that correspond to your `monoid_sum` and `monoid_max`, respectively.

#### `SumMonoid`

```
type SumMonoid int

func (s SumMonoid) Identity() SumMonoid {
    return 0
}

func (s SumMonoid) Combine(r SumMonoid) SumMonoid {
    return s + r
}
```

The type `SumMonoid` satisfies the interface `Monoid[SumMonoid]`.

```
func TestSumMonoid(t *testing.T) {
    a := SumMonoid(3)
    b := SumMonoid(7)
    c := SumMonoid(10)
    want := SumMonoid(20)
    got := CombineMonoids(a, b, c)
    if got != want {
        t.Fail()
    }
}
```

#### `MaxMonoid`

```
type MaxMonoid int

func (m MaxMonoid) Identity() MaxMonoid {
    return math.MinInt
}

func (m MaxMonoid) Combine(n MaxMonoid) MaxMonoid {
    if m > n {
        return m
    } else {
        return n
    }
}
```

The type `MaxMonoid` satisfies the interface `Monoid[MaxMonoid]`.

```
func TestMaxMonoid(t *testing.T) {
    a := MaxMonoid(-100)
    b := MaxMonoid(500)
    c := MaxMonoid(100)
    want := MaxMonoid(500)
    got := CombineMonoids(a, b, c)
    if got != want {
        t.Fail()
    }
}
```

#### What about a non-generic `Monoid` interface?

Similarly to what you suggested, you could, in principle, define the `Monoid` as a **non-generic interface**:

```
type Monoid interface {
    Identity() Monoid
    Combine(Monoid) Monoid
}
```

The problem is that the original type of the particular monoid (e.g., `SumMonoid` or `MaxMonoid`) will be *erased* to just the interface `Monoid`.

Combining a `SumMonoid` with a `MaxMonoid` makes no sense – you would place type assertions inside of the `Combine` method implementation that will lead to a panic if the *dynamic type* of the two monoids to be combined differ. So, the solution based on the generic interface seems to be more robust.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone's help and kindness!

I successfully defined monoid structure.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type monoid interface {
    get() interface{}         // type of interface{} depends on each monoid type.
    op(monoid, monoid) monoid // mapping_function(monoid,monoid) -> monoid（binary operations in monoid)
    ide() monoid              // identity_function() -> monoid (return Identity element)
}

type monoid1 struct {
    val int
    sum int
}

type monoid2 struct {
    name  string
    power int
}

func (m monoid2) get() interface{} {
    return m
}

func (m monoid2) op(x, y monoid) monoid {
    a := x.get().(monoid2)
    b := y.get().(monoid2)
    if len(a.name) > len(b.name) {
        return monoid2{a.name, a.power + b.power}
    } else {
        return monoid2{b.name, a.power + b.power}
    }
}

func (m monoid2) ide() monoid {
    return monoid2{"", 0}
}

func (m monoid1) get() interface{} {
    return m
}
func (m monoid1) op(x, y monoid) monoid {
    a := x.get().(monoid1)
    b := y.get().(monoid1)
    return monoid1{a.val + b.val, a.sum + b.sum}
}

func (m monoid1) ide() monoid {
    return monoid1{0, 0}
}

func main() {
    a := []monoid{monoid2{"Jame", 100}, monoid2{"Tom", 1010}, monoid2{"BOB SMITH", 1111}, monoid1{1, 1}, monoid1{2, 2}, monoid1{3, 3}}
    b := []monoid{monoid2{"Trump", 111}, monoid2{"MaryJames", 1234}, monoid2{"Cachy", 123245}, monoid1{1, 1}, monoid1{2, 2}, monoid1{3, 3}}
    for i := 0; i < 6; i++ {
        fmt.Println(a[i].op(b[i], a[i]))
    }
    return
}
```