# generics: constraint to a type with a function returning itself

Tags: go, generics

Is it possible to write a generic type constraint so that the type contains a function returning the same type or is it the same problem as with normal interfaces? Example use-case would be a builder with chainable methods.

Let's say I have a builder `IntFoo` which has a `SetFoo` method responsible for setting the `foo` field to some value. [Playground link](https://go.dev/play/p/tz3l-R7Xs9T)

```
type IntFoo struct {
    foo int
}

func (me *IntFoo) SetFoo(foo int) *IntFoo {
    me.foo = foo
    return me
}
```

Now I might have several builders like this one with different types and I'd like to define a constraint like this:

```
type Builder[F any] interface {
    SetFoo(F) Builder[F] // this return type is problematic
}
```

and some function consuming the Builder-constrained type like so:

```
// some generic demo function
func demo[E Builder[F], F any](builder E, foo F) {
    builder.SetFoo(foo)
    return
}
```

Trying to call the demo function

```
    e := &IntFoo{}
    demo(e, 2)
```

results in an error:

```
[compiler InvalidTypeArg] [E] *IntFoo does not implement Builder[int] (wrong type for method SetFoo)
        have SetFoo(foo int) *IntFoo
        want SetFoo(int) Builder[int]
```

Comment: related: [Recursive type constraint using a defined type rather than a type literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64468241)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to return the original type `E` - not the `Builder` interface - from your method:

```
type Builder[F, E any] interface {
    SetFoo(F) E
}
```

and then reworking `demo`, so the desired type `E` is relayed to the `Builder` type constraint:

```
func demo[E Builder[F, E], F any](bldr E, foo F) E {
    return bldr.SetFoo(foo)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/2K4D_nzMwU2

```
v := demo(e, 2)
fmt.Printf("%[1]T : %+[1]v\n", v) // *main.IntFoo : &{foo:2}
```