# How to implement a Golang interface method that takes itself as a parameter?

Tags: go, generics

I am trying to create a generic `Addable` type in Golang. Here's a toy example of what I'm trying to do:

```golang
package main

type Addable interface {
    // Note that `Add` takes an `Addable` as argument.
    Add(other Addable) Addable
}

type Point2d struct {
    x int
    y int
}

// Note that I cannot pass `other` as `Addable` because I need
// access to the fields x and y to implement the method.
func (p *Point2d) Add(other *Point2d) Addable {
    return &Point2d{p.x + other.x, p.y + other.y}
}

func SumAddables(a, b, c Addable) Addable {
    return a.Add(b).Add(c)
}
```

The above code does not compile. I get the following error:

```
./prog.go:16:9: cannot use &Point2d{…} (value of type *Point2d) as Addable value in return statement: *Point2d does not implement Addable (wrong type for method Add)
        have Add(*Point2d) Addable
        want Add(Addable) Addable
```

Link to Go playground: https://go.dev/play/p/eUmqZTZO1ow

Any idea how to implement such an interface in Golang?

Comment: The error shows the correct method signature, you must use `Add(Addable)`, which is different from `Add(*Point2d)`

Comment: Yes indeed, but note my comment in the code. I need to pass `other` as `*Point2d` to implement the `Add()` method because I need access to the `Point2d` fields. Hence my pickle.

Comment: You use a [type assertion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions) (or type switch) to extract the type you want from an interface

Comment: Thanks! Type assertion did the trick. Here's the updated Go playground with the fix for future readers: https://go.dev/play/p/dhGj65LQ-qX

Comment: Likely related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64468241/recursive-type-constraint-using-a-defined-type-rather-than-a-type-literal/68868092#68868092. See https://go.dev/play/p/0XTvSkKvnsk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to pass other as *Point2d to implement the Add() method because I need access to the Point2d fields.

That would  also be true of the implementation of `Add` for any other type.  If you want a generic `Add(Addable) Addable` you'll need to do a type assertion inside `Add` to handle the types you can add together.

```
func (p *Point2d) Add(other Addable) Addable {
    switch v := other.(type) {
    case *Point2d:
        return &Point2d{p.x + v.x, p.y + v.y}
    default:
        panic(fmt.Errorf("Unhandled type %T", other))
    }
}
```

(Full implementation at https://go.dev/play/p/KAFIhgjJ5Xs)

For what it's worth, this isn't really [Go Generics programming](https://go.dev/blog/intro-generics); it's simply satisfying the interface.