How do interfaces in Go work when implementing functions with parameters/return values of a generalised type?
I'm new to Go and a bit confused in how interfaces work when implemented, especially wrt. functions that have parameters. Say I have an interface with function foo that takes in an interface:
type I interface {
  foo(x interface{})
}

And a types A and B as below:
type A struct {
  // stuff
}
type B struct {
  // stuff
}

(a *A) foo(b B) {
 // do something
}

Since, in this example, A has method foo, is it considered to have implemented I, even with the specification of B as the param rather than a general interface? I have the same question for the function's return types as well.
If not, how would one design an interface which allows a more general parameter/return type and for structs which implement it to specify the type?

It doesn't implement the interface — nor should it. If you had a var typed as I that was a *A, you could pass in any argument to its foo, right? What would happen if you passed in 1? How would foo(B) handle that? As for your second question, look into generics — they give you what you want, mostly.


A has method foo, is it considered to have implemented I

No.
Interface I consists of a method foo which accepts an interface{} parameter.  This does NOT mean that it accepts a single argument of any type.  It means it accepts an argument implementing the specific interface with an empty method set; all types are compatible with this interface, so a value of any type may be supplied where this interface is specified.
It may help you to adopt the any type for such arguments (supported from go 1.18):
type I interface {
  foo(x any)
}

To satisfy this interface, a type must implement a method foo accepting an any argument; it is not sufficient to implement a foo method with a single argument; the type of that argument (any) is still important.
What you appear to be seeking is a generic interface (generics also were introduced in go 1.18):
type I[T any] interface {
  foo(T)
}

The type parameter T on the generic interface I has the any constraint, meaning that any type may be supplied.
If type A implements a foo method accepting an argument of type B then this will be deemed to implement an interface I[B]:
type I[T any] interface {
    foo(B)
}

type A struct{}

type B struct{}

func (A) foo(B) { log.Println("it works") }

func main() {
    var a any = A{}

    c := a.(I[B])
    c.foo(B{})
}

playground
a is initialised with a value of type A, but a itself is of any type so cannot be used directly to invoke the foo() method.
c is initialised by coercing a to the interface I[B], allowing the foo(B) method to be called.
Whether this helps you with your specific use case I cannot say without more details of exactly what I, A and B represent in your code and what you are trying to achieve.
Without those details, answers addressing the technical particulars of the language's type system may inadvertently direct you down an unhelpful path.

Thanks! Is it possible to bound the generic type T? Similar to how in Java there is the ? extends and ? super keywords, does Go have that feature too?

@NamitDeb Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64468241/recursive-type-constraint-using-a-defined-type-rather-than-a-type-literal/68868092#68868092

@NamitDeb if by "bounds" you mean "constraints" then yes.  In the example above the 'any ' constraint is used - this is the most relaxed constraint, allowing the use of, literally, any type.  But I don't think Golang constraints are directly comparable with Java; they may not offer all of the "features" you may be looking for.  See "Type Constraints" in the language spec: https://go.dev/ref/spec
