# How to define a type a 'typeof this' for in the interface

Tags: typescript

If I have case where I have interface method that must return type of implementing class I will delcare such construct as

```
interface Cloneable<T>{
  clone():T;
}

class A implements Cloneable<A>{
  clone():A {
    return new A();
  }
  public sayA(){
    console.log("AAAA");
  }
}

class B implements Cloneable<B>{
clone():B {
  return new B();
}
  public sayB(){
    console.log('BBB');
  }
}

new A().clone().sayA();
new B().clone().sayB();
```

Is it possible to get rid of `T` from `Cloneable` so I can ommit it in every implementation? It could be something like (invalid but understandable)

```
interface Cloneable{
  clone(): typeof this;
}
```

so the class would look like

```
class A implements Cloneable(){
    clone():A{}
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=28&ssc=1&pln=4&pc=1#code/FAiWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjaACAwgGwPbmogEZbQA8AKgHwDewaayu%20AFAJQBc5A3MAL4iNEAZyFoAgmlABbAA4kp0KKOx4CxMmJp0GTaG3YTa9erGiQArrHBp8Ad3Fse9fvRnnioZGiGIAnmLYjY2Q8IRwSADpcAHNmACIxRLE41ic0fn5gQRE0ACFJWXlFSGVdIhJSXK1GVX18oNMLKxtoe1zHPm03Dy8fX3bWIPoQ8DDImOYAclyZydTtDJA7B1YImpZVvoD55YG13TYIvoGeECA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "this" type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types

```
interface Cloneable {
    clone(): this;
}

class A implements Cloneable {
    clone(): this {
        return new A() as this;
    }
    public sayA(): void {
        console.log("AAAA");
    }
}

class B implements Cloneable {
    clone(): this {
        return new B() as this;
    }
    public sayB(): void {
        console.log("BBB");
    }
}

new A().clone().sayA();
new B().clone().sayB();
```

As you see, you'll have to do a cast to "this".

This question was already answered here: [Creating a generic "Cloneable" interface in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66498870/creating-a-generic-cloneable-interface-in-typescript)

Comment: I was close i guess.