# java generics observer pattern?

Tags: java, generics, observer-pattern

I know there are many (!) Q/A on this general topic; but haven't yet been able to resolve my specific approach.

I adapted this code from a Scala example by Odersky, which shows mutually recursive generic types to show a bi-directional link ability between Observer & Observed.

In Subject::publish() when I broadcast the event to all observers, even though my type is Subject<S,O>, and the target Observer is of type <S,O> and thus also its notify method; I get a type error,

> The method notify(S) in the type Observer<S,O> is not applicable for
> the arguments (Subject<S,O>)

unless I explicitly cast the passed argument to notify().

> obs.notify( (S) this );
> The types seem right, but the compiler disagrees(!).

May be something silly, but it eludes me. TIA

```
abstract class Subject< S extends Subject<  S, O >,
                        O extends Observer< S, O > > {
    private final List< O > observers = new ArrayList<O>();
    void subscribe( O obs ) { observers.add( obs ); }
    void publish() {
        for ( final O obs : observers )
            // TThe method notify(S) in the type Observer<S,O> is not applicable for the arguments (Subject<S,O>)
            obs.notify( this ); // (S)this   ??
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------
abstract class Observer< S extends Subject<  S, O >,
                         O extends Observer< S, O > > {
    abstract void notify( S sub );
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------
class Sensor extends Subject< Sensor, Display > {
    double value = 0.0;
    String name  = "";
    Sensor(String nm) { name = nm; }
    
    void changeValue( final double v ) {
        value = v;
        publish();
    }
    public String toString() { return "Sensor:" + name; }
}

class Display extends Observer< Sensor, Display > {
    void notify( Sensor sub ) {  // Note typed argument!
        System.out.println( sub  + " has value " + sub.value );
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------
public class SubjectObserver {
    public static void main( final String[] notUsed ) {
        final Display o = new Display();
        final Sensor  s = new Sensor("Temperature");
        s.subscribe( o );
        s.changeValue( 1 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***You've almost got it right!***

The self-bounded (or recursive) type declarations imply a several subtle nuances. Given your observer declaration we can state that:

```
abstract class Observer<S extends Subject<S, O>, O extends Observer<S, O>> {
    abstract void notify(S sub);
}
```

1. The construct `<S extends Subject<S, O>` makes sure that only subtypes of type `Subject<S, O>` are permitted as type arguments,
   meaning that `notify(S sub)` cannot accept the `Subject` class itself, but only its descendants.
2. It ensures the inheritance relationship between a subtype and an instantiation of Subject is of the form `Child extends Subject<Child, O>` meaning a subtype such as `Sensor extends Subject<NotASensorItself, O>` would be impossible (which is what you actually want)

---

Speaking of the `Subject#publish` method, by using `THIS` you're effectively forcing an observer to accept the `Subject` (the parent)
which does not conform the declared bound (`S` ≠ `Subject<S, O>`) hence you got the error:

```
void publish() {
    for (final O obs : observers)
        obs.notify(this); <<< Here only S are acceptable
}
```

when in fact you wanted the `obs.notify(XXX)` to accept a **Clild** instance and one of the options to do so - is to pass that reference along with the method invocation from a **Clild** directly:

```
void publish(S subject) {
    for (final O obs : observers)
        obs.notify(subject);
}
```

And the Sensor implementation:

```
class Sensor extends Subject<Sensor, Display> {
    ...
    void changeValue(final double v) {
        value = v;
        publish(this); << Here it passes itself, so now it conforms the bound for `S`
    }
}
```

A couple of links that might be helpful to grok mind-bending recursive types:

1. http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ106
2. https://medium.com/@hazraarka072/fluent-builder-and-powering-it-up-with-recursive-generics-in-java-483005a85fcd

Comment: Thanks for the note and approach.

I think however that a bounded generic <A extends B> includes all classes <A<=B>, i.e. includes B and all sub-classes of B, it does not mean only (A<B).

Comment: Your approach is good in that it explicitly passes a Sensor::this reference from the Sensor to the Subject::publish method.
What is interesting is that my former version passed the same value, but the "this" reference used in the publish().notify(this) method also had Subject::this, the same type, as one can verity using getClass().getTypeName().

So both had the same type - "Sensor extends Subject" & "Subject"; notify() should treat these the same, since the <A extends B> means (A<=B) and includes type A, not strictly (A<B).

Comment: @guthrie The holds true only for non-recursive declaration `Thing<A extends B>` where a method `Thing#doSomething(A thing)` would allow either `B` or its subtypes. Given the recursive declaration as `Thing<A extends Thing<A>>` - means that a type `Thing<A>` should be such that its type parameter `A` is a subtype of `Thing<A>` so now only subclasses satisfy the bound:  `ChildThing extends Thing<ChildThing>`.

Put simply - the `Thing` itself just cannot satisfy the bound for `A` as it would have to be a subtype of itself a the same time (which is not possible) `Thing<Thing<Thing<Thing...`

Comment: @guthrie The recursive-type bound deserves a discussion on its own. You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385949/what-does-recursive-type-bound-in-generics-mean/64901718#64901718) comment for more clarity

Comment: Thank you - I had missed the impact of the recursive type on the extends bound usage.