# How to define a general interface for several type-specific classes?

Tags: java, generics

While trying to program to interfaces, I regularly find myself in the following situation:

- I have several very similar classes representing containers or algorithms for different types.
- I would like to define a common interface for these classes.

Consider, e.g., a string container.
Such a container will likely have string processing methods.
Since those methods are easily represented using generic interfaces, I am ignoring them.
Here, I want to focus on methods that can be used to process or provide references to other string containers:

```java
public class StringContainer {
    StringContainer produce() {
        return new StringContainer();
    }

    void consume(StringContainer stringContainer) {
    }
}
```

This class can be used just fine in code like:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringContainer stringContainer = new StringContainer();
        stringContainer.produce();
        stringContainer.consume(stringContainer);
    }
}
```

The problem is: I'm using a concrete class and not an interface to refer to the string container.
What if I want to introduce a double container or a list container later and want to leave the rest of the code as is?

Maybe generics could form a solution to this problem?
Here is my try.
I first define a generic container class:

```java
interface Container<T> {
    Container<T> produce();

    void consume(Container<T> container);
}
```

I then create type-specific implementations of the form:

```java
public class StringContainer implements Container<String> {
    @Override
    public Container<String> produce() {
        return new StringContainer();
    }

    @Override
    public void consume(Container<String> container) {
    }

    public void consume(StringContainer container) {
    }
}
```

The above classes can be used as follows:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container<String> stringContainer = new StringContainer();
        stringContainer.produce();
        stringContainer.consume(stringContainer);
    }
}
```

However, the above approach has several drawbacks:

1. The `consume(Container<String> container)` method accepts other types than `StringContainer`.
2. In `consume(Container<String> container)`, the parametrized type `Container<String>` has to be used when processing `container`. I can't assign it to `StringContainer` variables (without type checks or casts).
3. The alternative `consume(StringContainer container)` method is defined for `StringContainer` objects, but can't be called from a `Container<String>` reference.
4. Finally, to me, the line `Container<String> stringContainer = new StringContainer();` has an awkward-looking notation that suggests a diamond operator is missing in `new StringContainer()`.

What is the idiomatic way to define a general interface for several type-specific classes, which doesn't have (all) the above drawbacks?

Should I ignore point 4 and address points 1 and 2 by adding type checks/casts, throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException` or `IllegalArgumentException` in case passed objects aren't `StringContainer`s?
Or is there another way to use generics? Can type bounds help me, for example?
Or should I look for a solution outside of generics?

---

Update:

Based on the answers given so far, I have come to realize that I had conflicting goals:

- On the one hand, I wanted to restrict the types accepted by container methods (as described by points 1 and 2).
- On the other hand, I wanted to address and pass container types using an interface reference (as hinted at by point 3 and my implicit desire to keep the second `main` method as is).

I now see that these goals cannot both be reached statically.
Since I don't want to rephrase my question in retrospect, I'll forget about my second (rather implicit) goal and mark the first-posted solution that addressed points 1 and 2 as the answer.

Comment: IMO, what makes the difference is that your *interface* designed around `Container<T>` rather than `T`. In other words, if `T` were the parameter types in your method signatures, you wouldn't have this problem with generic types.

Comment: It seems like there's two different things you're trying to be generic over here, i.e. the contained type _and_ the container type. Can you elaborate a bit why a `StringContainer` is producing and consuming containers rather than strings?

Comment: Why is 4 a problem? Why did you expect there to be a diamond operator in the first place? It seems like it is your expectation that is wrong in the case of 4.

Comment: @tzaman My StringContainer will also produce and consume strings, but the methods for it don't cause me trouble so I left them out. An example of a StringContainer of this form could be a node in a linked list that contains both data (strings) and references to other nodes (containers) of strings.

Comment: @ernest_k Exactly, interface methods like `set(T value)` and their corresponding implementation `set(String value)` would be just fine. Since those methods don't cause me trouble, I left them out of the example code.

Comment: So is it intended that one concrete type of `StringContainer` should be able to consume another type? Or is that what you're trying to prevent with type checks?

Comment: @Sweeper I'm much more used to generic implementations of generic interfaces than non-generic ones from seeing code like `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`. I wasn't necessarily expecting a diamond operator in my code. The absence of it looked curious to me, though.

Comment: @tzaman I would like to see that the type `StringContainer implements Container<String>` does not accept types other than `StringContainer`, just like the original non-interface-implementing version. That's why I was thinking of type checks. Maybe I'm entirely down the wrong road, though?

Comment: Agree with @Sweeper, #4 is just nonsense. That's not a drawback. That's your expectations being wrong. I can make a `class MyStringList implements List<String>` and instantiate it with `List<String> strs = new MyStringList()`. The type parameter is already specified by the class. Instantiators don't need to specify it either explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: @Michael Okay, thanks for that :) I'm still getting used to Java, so it's good to hear what are common (or not) idioms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? It's called a recursive type bound.

```
interface Container<T extends Container<T>> {
    T produce();

    void consume(T container);
}

class StringContainer implements Container<StringContainer> {
    @Override
    public StringContainer produce() {
        return new StringContainer();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void consume(StringContainer container) {
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks promising and surprising (to me). I hadn't expected all the <String>s to have gone missing. I guess @ernest_k is right that there are two parts to my API: the string-processing part that I ignored in my question and the container 'communication' that is addressed by your answer.

Comment: I wasn't aware that we could use a cool construction like `StringContainer implements Container<StringContainer>`. I also have trouble wrapping my head around the recursive type bound. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/64901718/12911324 I get a rough understanding of it. Regardless of whether I write `interface Container<T>` or your variant, I can't pass anything else than `StringContainer`s (or its children) to `consume`, though. An interface reference, siblings of `StringContainer` -- nothing is allowed. I guess this is because Container itself does not implement a generic interface.

Comment: "*I can't pass anything else than StringContainers (or its children) to consume*" I thought you wanted this. In point #1 in your question, you complained about the opposite.

Comment: Yes, I realize that now (: And it makes me wonder whether I am chasing an impossible goal. I'd like to use interface references like `Container<String>` or `Container<StringContainer>` to refer to `StringContainer` objects. Ideally, `consume` accepts these reference as well -- otherwise, why bother creating the interface? But I don't want the `StringContainer` methods to accept other `Container` implementations than `StringContainer`s ...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have two APIs, and you should treat them separately with separate interfaces. Yes, you can merge them into the same interface with distinct method names.

I think you should have two interfaces for your "containers" and for your "containers of containers". Here's what I'd make it:

```
interface Container<T> {
    T produce();
    void consume(T container);
}

interface MetaContainer<T, R extends Container<T>> {
    R produceContainer();
    void consumeContainer(R container);
}

class StringContainer implements Container<String>, MetaContainer<String, StringContainer> {
    @Override
    public String produce() {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public void consume(String container) {
    }

    @Override
    public StringContainer produceContainer() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void consumeContainer(StringContainer container) {
    }
}
```

I implemented both interfaces using the same class to emulate your `StringContainer` class.

Comment: `MetaContainer` doesn't need the `T` parameter, does it? Can't it just be `MetaContainer<R extends Container<R>>` like in Micheal's answer?

Comment: @Sweeper you got me to think. In my mind, that should work, but eclipse rejects `class StringContainer implements Container<String>, MetaContainer<StringContainer>` when `MetaContainer` is declared like that. Besides, I think with the recursive bound, `T` becomes both the "contained" and the "container" types (and it seems OP wanted both types of signatures). Need to think more.

Comment: @ernest_k The extra T bound means it's not recursive. In your current version, the MetaContainer takes a Container of *something* (T), in our case String. If you use a recursive type bound, it expects a Container of *itself*, i.e. `Container<StringContainer>`, which StringContainer is not; it's a `Container<String>`. But since T isn't used in MetaContainer, a wildcard does the same. `R extends Container<?>`

Comment: @Michael Correct. And my understanding is that OP wants `StringContainer` to be both `Container<String>` and `Container<StringContainer>`... And ofc I think the latter should be something else, i.e. `MetaContainer<Container<String>>` (or ofc `MetaContainer<StringContainer>` or whatever we want to structure it as).

Comment: @ernest_k You correctly inferred that I'd like `StringContainer`s to play two roles. On the one hand, I'd like them to be able to consume and produce (or simply set and get) strings. On the other hand, I'd like them to be able to keep references to each other. One specific case, where I'd like to apply this scheme is in the creation of nodes for a linked list, that would both contain data and refer to other nodes with data of that same type. In my efforts to generalize the problem (to other cases I want to solve), I may have abstracted the core out of it, though ...

Comment: Thanks for all your input! @ernest_k I can see how you separated the `Container<String>` and `Container<StringContainer>` responsibilities with the `MetaContainer<...>` interface. From what I understand, `MetaContainer<T, R extends Container<T>>` can be simplified to `MetaContainer<R extends Container<?>>`. That means we essentially arrive at Michael's solution (for the container-container part), right? I'll then select his answer as it first answered points 1 and 2 of my question, but I thank you for going the extra mile of trying to construe my broader intent.